# How do I take the innerHtml.text() and format it when inserting it into a .txt file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've taken [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zarich/TzVd3/378/) and added a line to it to remove all the [html tags](http://jsfiddle.net/TzVd3/918/).

My question is this: How do I format this to look nice in a text file when there is a ton of data, dynamically added to the table I am pulling from?

```
$("#lnkExportToTxt").click(function (e) {
            toastr.success("Your .txt file is being generated!");
            downloadInnerHtml(fileName, "gridResults");
            e.preventDefault();
        })
```

I appreciate all the responses.

Comment: There is a Node package called html-to-pdf. It will take whatever HTML you feed it and transpile the markup to the PDF using the stiles designated in the HTML. The problem you got is that .txt files do not accept complex formatting. They are simple text. If you want formatting, you have to output to a format that allows text formatting (like PDF).

Comment: @Korgrue I guess formatting might be the wrong term. I want to make it so not everything is strung along as one giant blob. For example, after a name, have it start a new line.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.

That is more complex. You will have to add \n newline characters in the original string each place you want to break to newline.

Comment: Thats exactly what you should do. Something like this would work.

display_txt = display_txt.replace("<br />", /\n/g);

Comment: @Korgrue Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It only adds \n into the .txt file instead of actually moving things to a new line. Any further ideas? I've been searching for a solution but everything just seems to want to bring it FROM a .txt, instead of TO a .txt.